# Laravel Mail method from()

Tags: laravel, email

Could I put a ENV variable from `config\mail.php`such here /*

```
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Global "From" Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
| the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
| used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
|
*/

'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'noreply@****.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', '****'),
],
```

Because i tried to build a message from a Contact Form in my laravel app and I would like to use

```
public function build()
    {
        return $this->from()->view('email.contact');
    }
```

with a dynamic variable in from method but I would like to fix this issue ... :/

Possible or not?

Best regard

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand the question but you can use your "config email" like this :

```
config('mail.from.address')
```